# error: Incorrect syntax near '̣'. .When I am creating CHECK constraints for tables. Everyone helped me with

Tags: sql

```
USE Movies
GO

ALTER TABLE Movie
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Movie CHECK ̣(Rating = 'G' OR Rating = 'PG' OR Rating = 'R' OR Rating = 'NC17' OR Rating = 'NR')
GO

ALTER TABLE Rental
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Due_date CHECK ̣(Due_date >= Rental_date)
GO
```

I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '̣'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in these topics, but I think it need a some symbols.
try the next ones alternatives... I hope you beat this problem

```
USE Movies 
GO

ALTER TABLE Movie 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Movie CHECK ̣(Rating='G' OR Rating='PG' OR Rating='R' OR Rating='NC17' OR Rating='NR') (might be here)
GO (here) 

ALTER TABLE Rental 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Due_date CHECK ̣(Due_date >= Rental_date) 
GO (semicolon)
```